# Determining the volume of a set

Tags: integration, volume

The answer should be obvious to me but I am not quite certain I am getting the right idea.

It is asked to calculate the volume of $M=\{(x,y,z) : 2z=x^2+y^2, z<2\}$. So this gives me the following:

$0<z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}<2 \implies 0<x^2+y^2<4$. So let's put $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then $0<r<2$. And the integral in cylindrical coordinates then becomes:

$\int_M=\int_{z=0}^{z=2}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=2}rdr d\theta dz = 8\pi$.

Is this the correct way?

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you sure for $2z=x^2+y^2$?

Comment: @DonAntonio the definition for M is not so clear to me, is it a volume?

Comment: @gimusi It is a 3-D surface, between the $\;z=0\,-$ plane and the $\;z=2\;$ plane. It looks like a bowl whose minimal point is on the origin...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes indeed the condition for M should be $2z\ge x^2+y^2$ and $r$ varies from $0$ to $\sqrt{2z}$.

Comment: @gimusi Well, not really. when using cylindrical coordinates we do project the whole thing on the $\;xy\;$ plane (or with its official name: the $\;z=0\;$ plane), and then $\;r,\,\theta\;$ vary as the surface's projection on this plane requires. In this case, the surface's projection is the canonical circle of radius $\;2\;$, namely: $\;x^2+y^2=4\;$ , and thus $\;0\le r\le 2\;,\;\;0\le \theta\le 2\pi\;$ . As $\;z\;$ remains itself, it varies $\;r^2=x^2+y^2\le z\le 2\;$ ...And now that I am writing this I can spot a mistake in the OP's work! Because the limits for $\;z\;$ are wrong....

Comment: @DonAntonio By my interpretation, for $z\in(0,2)$ fixed the condition $2z=x^2+y^2$ is a circle thus M is a surface not a volume. The condition should be $2z\ge x^2+y^2$ in order to deal with a volume.

Comment: @gimusi Of course $\;M\;$ is a surface! What else could it be? But hte OP is asking about "its volume", and as I explian above it is not tompletely clear what he means. I think it is meant the volume of the contents of the bowl, meaning: the volume of the domain enclosed by the bowl between $\;z=0\;$ and $\;z=2\;$ . And in cylindrical coord., $\;z\;$ is kept as it is, and $\;x,y\;$ are changed by the polar coordinates...and thus $\;2z\ge x^2+y^2\implies z\ge\frac12r^2\;$ ,as written in my answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed it is not properly described, to be a volume we need the mentioned inequality, otherwise we should request for the volume enclosed by M. Anyway the volume of the bowl in cylindrical coordinates is obtained by the set up $$\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta\int_0^2\,dz\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2z}}r\,dr=4\pi$$ or also by your one, even if I found that way a bit less natural as choice.

Comment: @JordyMolenaar Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Check the bound for $r$ we should have $r$ from $0$ to $f(z)$, that is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta\int_0^2\,dz\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2z}}r\,dr=2\pi\int_0^2z\,dz=4\pi$$

Comment: Oh, I see now, the bound for r should be from 0 to $\sqrt{(2z)}$

Comment: Which agrees with the calculation. $z=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$. Then volume is $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 z rdr d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2  \frac{r^3}{2} dr d\theta = 4\pi$

Comment: Indeed in the definition for $M$ it should be $...2z\ge x^2+y^2$ otherwise M would be a surface.

Comment: Very nice...and this is exactly the same as I did, with the order of the two rightmost integrals interchanged...:) . Anyway, the main problem here is to be sure the volume **of what** is required. +1

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Yes I meant the volume enclosed by the bowl. Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the volume *of the domain enclosed by the three dimensional surface* $\;M\;$ between $\;0\le z\le 2\;$ , then the integral is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_{r^2/2}^2r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta=2\pi\int_0^2r\left(2-\frac12r^2\right)\,dr=2\pi\int_0^2\left(2r-\frac12r^3\right)\,dr=$$

$$=\left.2\pi\left(r^2-\frac18r^4\right)\right|_0^2=2\pi\left(4-2\right)=4\pi$$

What you calculate with

$$\int_M\,\mathrm dV=\int_{z=0}^{z=2}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=2}rdr d\theta dz $$

Is the volume of the domain between the $\;xy\,-$ plane and the surface $\;M\;$ itself (i.e, between the floor and the bowl, **not the volume enclosed by the bowl itself!**)

As you wrote it it is a little confusing, but I think they meant the first one...

Comment: Then finally we are now at the same point!